# Block certain IP addresses

Tags: 7

How to block certain IP addresses if we receive too many GET requests from particular IP addresses for a Drupal 7 website?

Comment: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/blocking-ips/blocking-a-specific-ip-address-in-drupal

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 has IP address blocking feature by default.

1. Login to admin
2. Navigate to configuration page
3. Click on "IP address blocking" which available in under People panel
4. Add IP address which you wanted to block.

OR

Navigate to below page 
http://[yourwebsitename.com]/admin/config/people/ip-blocking

[image: IP Address blocking]

Comment: Thanks. could you please say how to prevent an IP address if we receive GET request from a particular IP address . Do we have any contributed module?

Comment: This answer doesn't prevent GET requests